# Guidance: converting parallel incremental nested loop to streams

Tags: groovy, java-8, stream, iteration, java-stream

I am trying to convert the following loop to Java stream.

```
def a = [12,34,5,64,24,56], b = [1,23,45]

for(int i=0;i<a.size();)
    for(int j=0;j<b.size() && a[i];j++)
        println a[i++]+","+b[j]
```

Output:

```
12,1
34,23
5,45
64,1
24,23
56,45
```

I tried few ways but I am not sure how to increment outer loop from inner loop. Any guidance is appreciated. The following code is the furthest I have done.

```
a.stream().forEach({x ->
    b.stream().filter({y-> y%2 != 0}).forEach({ y-> 
        println x+","+y
    });
});
```

Output:

```
12,1
12,23
12,45
34,1
34,23
34,45
5,1
5,23
5,45
64,1
64,23
64,45
24,1
24,23
24,45
56,1
56,23
56,45
```

Comment: Since this is not Java code, I have to ask. What does the condition `j<b.size() && a[i]` do? Especially the second part…

Comment: @Holger Sorry, I haven't mentioned the language used anywhere. Its groovy code. About the condition, `j<b.size()` is typical loop exit condition. Where as `a[i]` is an added condition which allows me to exit the inner loop when elements from outer loop list completes iteration.

Comment: What does “when elements from outer loop list completes iteration” mean? How can an `int` value complete the iteration?

Comment: I meant the iteration of object `a`. As you can see `a` is a list. By "elements from outer loop list completes iteration", I meant the values `[12,34,5,64,24,56]` of list `a`.

Comment: I still don’t understand under which conditions `&& a[i]` will end the loop.

Comment: @Holger `a[i]` tests for not null. It is equivalent of `a[i] != null` in Java. Groovy has simplified syntax.

Comment: So you assume that one of the elements of your list of numbers could be `null` and the operation is supposed to stop on the first `null`? That’s an important information and a non-obvious constraint. As you can see, the current answer does not contain that stop condition.

Comment: @Holger Exactly my point. And thank you for patiently understanding the question. I very much appreciate that.

Comment: Nitpicking: it is not `a[i]!=null` but "Groovy Truth"; internally this is a cast to boolean and so also 0, "", [], ... are falsey here.

Comment: Starting with Java 9, Streams offer the `takeWhile` operation, to stop when a condition is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

```
IntStream.range(0, left.length)
         .mapToObj(x -> left[x] + " " + right[x % right.length])
         .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

where `left` is `a` and `right` is `b`